# How can I detect if GC.Collect() was run manually?

Tags: .net, garbage-collection

I suspect a library I'm using is violently calling `GC.Collect()`, which is causing issues. How can I confirm if such a manually triggered collection is indeed happening?

My program has high memory throughput itself, but many 100 Gen 2 collections *per second* still seem very unlikely to me, especially considering it's using only a few 100 MB of RAM.

Comment: This could help: https://github.com/mattwarren/GCVisualisation Wont tell you who, but a profiler can help with that.

Comment: @leppie Thanks, I've tried it. The screen was scrolling down awfully fast. Did not help with the problem at hand, but may surely come back in helpful later.

Answer (score 4):

There is a [performance counter for that](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/maoni/2004/06/03/gc-performance-counters/), "Induced GC" ticks up every time GC.Collect() is called.  Use Perfmon.exe to look at it, right-click the graph > Add Counters > .NET CLR Memory > # Induced GC > select your exe.

A decent decompiler is always useful as well (ILSpy, Reflector, etc), you can tell the author exactly what method he needs to fix.

Comment: ".NET CLR Memory" is missing on my system, and so far any attempts to enable it again failed, but I'll try again. Surely that's a good way to find out _if_ there is a potential culprit.